# Import products with meta-data using WP All Import plugin?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce to setup my online store and I've set my products up with meta-data fields and when I need to import the products to my live site with csv. My columns have meta:_branchid, _a_price_field, meta:_orderlvl.

I want to use WP All Import because I have a huge database (32k rows), but I get confused with the mapping of the fields.

Also, is there another way to import large number of products faster in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the default WooCommerce import engine instead. I think it has a better mapping system than WP All Import.